# How to make cargo doc warn about missing documentation for public functions in module in a binary crate?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rustdoc

When I add `#![warn(missing_docs)]` to my main.rs the only warning that it gives me is that the that there is no documentation for the crate (as it should), but I would like that the modules in my project also warn me that there is missing documentation for all public functions within the modules. Is there a way to make cargo doc warn about missing documentation in modules as well?
Project Structure:

```
.
├── Cargo.lock
├── Cargo.toml
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
├── src
│  ├── database.rs
│  ├── files.rs
│  ├── main.rs
│  └── validate.rs
└── target
```

I tried adding `#![warn(missing_docs)]` and `#![warn(rustdoc::missing_crate_level_docs)]` to the top of the main.rs and all module files and it did not warn me of any missing documentation. I was expecting cargo doc to warn about missing documentation all of the undocumented functions in all of the modules but it did not do that.

Comment: Are the modules public? Because it warns for me.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman That was it. Added  the pub keyword before mod "module name" in the binary crate and it now warns me. Thanks friend.